# Using librosa to decelerate my audio in Python but it's not natural

Tags: python, librosa

I have created a Python program that uses `librosa`.
I am using `librosa` to decelerate my audio.

After processing the audio vocals sound like two [voices] and weak.

How can I use `pyrubberband.pyrb.time_stretch()` to return the voice to natural and normal cadence?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the librosa code you use for deceleration? Why not use rubber and for both slow down and speed up?